# Swift - understanding return types in recursion: when should return the function vs. just return on its own

Tags: swift, recursion

This may be a little too general for this forum, but hoping someone can explain this in a way that makes sense to my brain.  I've tried reading and researching and have found lots of examples - but I still don't understand the "why" which means that I am not understanding exactly how a program comes back from a function return.

Here is a very simple function I wrote that solves a puzzle using backwards recursion.  It works well.

```
func solver(grid: [[Int]])->[[Int]] {  
    var returnGrid = constraintPropogation(grid: grid)
    if contradictionCheck(grid: returnGrid) == false {
         return returnGrid
    } else {
        if returnGrid.flatMap({$0}).filter({$0 == 3}).count == 0 {
            print("SOLVED**********")
            gridPrint(grid: returnGrid)
            print()
            stopFlag = true
            stopAnswer = returnGrid
            return returnGrid
        } else {
            let randStart = getRandomStart(grid: returnGrid)
            returnGrid[randStart.x][randStart.y] = 0
            solver(grid: returnGrid)
            returnGrid[randStart.x][randStart.y] = 1 
            solver(grid: returnGrid)
            }   
        }
    if stopFlag == true {return stopAnswer}
    return solver(grid: returnGrid)
    }
```

My issue is understanding the returns.  In the third line of the function if a contradiction check fails this means that we've gone down a path that would not be possible.  Therefore we return.  That makes sense.  The second return in the middle of the function occurs when the puzzle is solved, so it makes sense to return there.  But the last one at the end "return solver(grid: returnGrid)" is challenging to my understanding.  Here we are returning but also calling this same function again.  This is not going deeper into the potential solution path (that happens in the "else" section where the function is called).  Why do we need to call the function again rather than just returning?  What is happening under the hood?  Does the return happen first where we "pop back up a level" and then we are calling the function again effectively one rung higher on the stack?  When I write these words I realize that I have a vague understanding - but somehow it is not all clicking together for me.

Am at the point now that when I'm writing functions that involve recursion I just try both returning on own or returning and calling function again to see which one achieves what I want.  But I'd really like to understand it rather than just guessing.  If anyone had a simple explanation I would appreciate it.

Comment: To answer your specific question, your function has to return an integer array of integer arrays. Therefore, the function can return this array of arrays explicitly `return returnGrid` or it can return an object that itself returns this array of arrays. To the Swift compiler, an actual integer array of integer arrays `[[2], [9]]` is no different than a function that returns this array of arrays `solver(grid: [[2], [9]])`--they are the same type.

Answer (score 1):

Your function solver takes an array of arrays, and returns an array of arrays. Any call to return(something) returns that something to the caller.

Saying `return(someArrayOfArrays)` means you are done, and have a result.

Saying `return(solver(someArrayOfArrays))` says "call this function again, passing in a new value. Return whatever the result is as the function result." The current call to `solver()` is done doing work, and passes its intermediate results to another call to the function. That's the recursion. You can think of this as nesting a function call inside a function call inside a function call, or stacking function calls on top of each other.

The call to `solver(grid: returnGrid)` does not make any sense. That is a recursive call, but you ignore the result. Thus, that call does nothing useful. If your remove that line, it won't make any difference to the outcome. That line is saying "Go do a bunch of work and find an answer for me, but I will throw away your answer". The compiler should give you a "function result ignored" warning at that line.

Beyond that, I can't tell what your code is doing. It appears to be modifying at least one global variable, "stopAnswer". That suggests it's not a pure recursive function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, helpful.    In regard to the solver(grid: returnGrid) not returning anything that is not true.  That line makes the function recurse to the next level.  Eventually when the puzzle is solved the end result is printed out so we only get it then.  QUESTION: Is this poor programing form? (That is having a function that doesn't return anything immediately).  I'm new to this and don't want to develop any bad habits.

Comment: If you comment out that line I bet you get the same result. Then again, it looks like you're using global variables, so all bets are off.